# Probability that all submatrices of a certain size have full rank over a finite field

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields

Let $F = \mathbb{Z}_q$ be a finite field. Let $n \leq m' \leq m$. Pick a matrix $A \in F^{m \times n}$ such that each entry is chosen from a uniform distribution over $F$. Consider any $m' \times n$ submatrix of $A$ formed by choosing any $m'$ rows of $A$. What is the probability that every such submatrix $A'$ has full rank $n$?

Using the first equation [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82801731.pdf), I found that there are $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^{m'} - q^i) = q^{m' n} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1 - q^{i-m'})$ matrices of size $m' \times n$ with rank $n$, so the probability that any arbitrary $A'$ has rank $n$ is given by $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1 - q^{i-m'})$. I'm not sure if this helps to compute the probability that all $A'$ have full rank.

Even just a strong lower bound on this probability would help. Thank you!

Comment: IIRC from coding theory we get the special case that if $m´=n$ and $m>q+1$ the probability is zero.

Comment: Do you happen to know any resources I can refer to? I am interested in the case where $m,m’$ are much bigger than $n$.